# RxJava2 Completable does not combine as expected

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactive

My intention was to be able to pipeline a set amount of [Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) however, it does not work as expected as seen from the following test case.

```java
@Test
public void test_and_then() {

    Completable c1 = Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        System.out.println("<1>");
    });

    Completable c2 = Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        System.out.println("<2.1>");
        boolean test = true;
        if (test) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        System.out.println("<2.2>");
    });

    Completable c3 = Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        System.out.println("<3>");
    });


    Completable.complete()
            .andThen(c1)
            .andThen(c2)
            .andThen(c3)
            .test()
            .assertError(t -> true)
            .dispose();

    c3.test().assertNotSubscribed();
}
```

This results in the following output.

```java
<1>
<2.1>
<3>
java.lang.AssertionError: Subscribed! (latch = 0, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 1)
```

As seen in the [documentation of andThen](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#andThen-io.reactivex.CompletableSource-) it looks like it should not subscribe to any Completables added later if an error is detected in previous Completable.
My problem is, why "<3>" is printed, basically, that Completable is run. How can I prevent this and simply end the chain of compietables instead?
And why does it subscribe to the Completable c3 when the documentation indicates that this should not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it works as you expected. However, you are subscribing to `c3`:

```
c3.test().assertNotSubscribed();
```

This will subscribe to `c3` and print `<3>`.

If you remove that line, it'll work as you expect.

`test()` subscribes and gives you a test observer that you can do assertions on. It's just unfortunate the output order - it makes you think the stream is not stopped.

**Edit**

Regarding the comment "what's the purpose of `assertNotSubscribed` if it always fails".

This is quite a misconception to be honest. `test()` is not the single way you have to create `TestObserver`s. You can create a test observer like so

```
TestObserver<Void> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
```

You can use `assertNotSubscribed` to make sure you haven't subscribed the test observer yet. Actually, that method is supposed to check that `onSubscribe` hasn't been called. It's not meant to test that `dispose()` was called.

For this scenario, you'd have to do something like `assertTrue(testObserver.isDisposed())`. You can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4792).

Comment: Thanks for that answer, you are correct. But then what is the purpose of assertNotSubscribed if it will always fail? Do you mind editing your answer to incorporate this please.